# IBM Liberty where to place properties file required by multiple applications

Tags: spring-boot, websphere, websphere-liberty

-Multiple spring boot apps are deployed to IBM liberty 20x
All the Spring boot app should access properties from multiple properties file.
Acording to the reference https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/cwlp_sharedlibrary.html

tried below configuration in server.xml by creating folder "customProps" at "wlp\usr\servers\controller1"

```
<library id="allpropeties">
<fileset dir="${server.config.dir}/customProps" includes="*.properties" />
</library>
```

But gets the below error as applicaiton not able to locate the properties file:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [test.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Where to keep multiple common properties files and what configuration has to be added to server.xml

Answer (score 0):

As a simple answer you could try copying the properties file to the default global shared library location:

`${server.config.dir}/lib/global`

You could use this without additional server config, and/or read through some of the [doc](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_classloader_global_libs.html) for additional configuration considerations.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to go global, I think you also need to tell your applications to use the library. The doc you linked to contained an example of how to do that

```
<application location ="webStore.war">
   <classloader commonLibraryRef="someLibrary" />
</application>
```

So yours would look like

```
<application location ="<nameOfMyApp>">
   <classloader commonLibraryRef="allProperties" />
</application>
```

Also worth finding out if ${server.config.dir} resolves to where you expect it to.